# the requested operation can't be completed due to the security restriction in odoo12 POS?

Tags: security, odoo, odoo-12

i have more then 8 companies each one has it's own POS in multi comapny and all in same parent company, but most of them the get too much popup errors with different records while the cashier on the screen of the pos with restriction rules and this the content of error "the requested operation can't be due to the security restriction please contact your system administrator.

(document type: product, Operation: read)

(Records :[21343, 23423, 23434, ........], user: 9)

if i access the parent company and searched for the records i found it's belongs to another company , why this error appear and how can i get ride of it ?[image]

Edit

i'am using this record in product.template

['|','|',('company_id.child_ids','child_of',[user.company_id.id]),('company_id','child_of',[user.company_id.id]),('company_id','=',False)]

Comment: look for all security rules on the product.template/product.product

Comment: Check all the process occurring in your transaction. Might your custom code affecting here.

Comment: @KevalMehta that's happening while searching on pos

Comment: Which specific search is happening ?

Comment: @KevalMehta I found this error occurs while another pos is open in another company and id the other pos validate any order this error happens

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any custom modules related to stock picking/move or product?

We had this error in Odoo 13CE POS. We had multi-company set and multi counters.

For us, this error appeared when there are orders from another company. As an example:
Company A counter screen is on and idle
Company B counter takes an order and validates it
Company A now sees the error of security restriction

When concurrent orders happened with mult-company activities, this pop-up error showed. It was the result of a custom module related to pos and stock.picking & stock.move.

As our project of POS was for a short time (only one month) what we did was we configured pos categories. We removed company info from all products. Then assigned POS categories to each product. In the pos config settings, we restricted the product view by POS categories. By that, the products were filtered on the POS.

If you have custom addons, you could try to test the system without those modules and see the result.

Comment: this what actually happens with me, can you tell me how you solve it and what apps that can effects

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue on v12, with another app provider(Acespritech pos for v12 community). I open three companies using this app under same odoo web, all have different products and contacts,the first company will show this problem and when i set another 2, the 2 companies are fine.
If it is for SAAS use, it can be possible, but I try a lot to dig into it, I find it is a bug, as I cannot use administrator account to open it as well, it is not access right related.

Comment: my problem was caused because of custom app that displays quantities on pos